SVG Sector (FoV) Misalignment with Markers on Zoom in Leaflet: How to Maintain Alignment?
I am working on a Leaflet-based application where I overlay an image (a floor plan) and place draggable markers representing CCTV cameras.
For the CCTV cameras, I display their field of view (FoV) as an SVG sector rendered over the image.
(This is zoomed - fov is attached to marker) 
This is initial view (without zooming - fov is far away from marker 
At one zoom level, the FoV appears far from the marker.
At other zoom level, the FoV seems to stay attached or partially aligned with the marker.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Absolute positioning: Using pixel-based coordinates for the SVG path, but the misalignment persists when zooming.
Percentage-based positioning: Calculating the SVG coordinates as percentages of the image dimensions. While this scales better, it still misaligns when zooming
How can I ensure that the SVG sector representing the FoV stays perfectly aligned with its corresponding marker at any zoom level in Leaflet?
Since it's difficult to share all the relevant code in this post, attaching a CodeSandbox URL for sharing my progress so far:
codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-curran-fr2wz8

https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle
